# count files found by find function in a shell script and save them in an array

Tags: arrays, shell, file, find

I would like to make a shell script that finds a specific file and then asks the user which file he wants. But when I for example use the find command

```
(find . -name 2D.py)
```

it finds two files:

> ```
> ./Desktop/2D.py
> ./libcpab-master/2D.py
> ```

save these into a file:

```
file=$(find . -name 2D.py)
```

and counts them:

```
echo "${#key[@]}"
```

I get that only one name. It should be 2 files. 
Also when I save 'file' in a array, there is only one element.

Hope you can help.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: I have solved it. I need to write file=($file) after finding the different files :-).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the "file" variable as an array. Try this

```
> find . -name 2D.py
./Desktop/2D.py
./libcpab-master/2D.py
> set -A file
> file=$(find . -name 2D.py)
> echo "${file[*]}"
./Desktop/2D.py
./libcpab-master/2D.py
> echo "${file[*]}" > file_list
> cat file_list
./Desktop/2D.py
./libcpab-master/2D.py
> wc file_list
 2  2 39 file_list
>
```